# HTML5 download attribution not working for file without extension

Tags: html, download, href, mime-types, file-extension

I´m trying to use the 'download' attribute of *a href* to rename a file without extension, but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="/fileWithoutExtension" download="newName.pdf">
```

I tried with IE, Chrome and FF.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The download attribute only works in Chrome 14+ and Firefox 20+ so this May explain why you are not getting this to work. I suggest you do not use it as it is not yet widely used. Prefer some other alternatives.

**You can check that your attribute is supported with this javascript code, taken from here : http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-the-download-attribute/**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');

if(typeof a.download != "undefined")
{
   // download attribute is supported
}
else
{
  // download attribute is not supported
}
```

**If you want to change the filename then just use a server-sided PHP script:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFile.pdf"');
echo file_get_contents("your_original_file");
?>
```

and make your link like this

```
<a href="file.php"></a>
```